# garmin connectciq-sdk ommand monkeyc not found in openjdk apline docker container

Tags: bash, docker, ash, connectiq, monkeyc

I'm running openjdk:13-alpine docker container and mounted the garmin connectiq-sdk files into the container.
Trying to run monkeyc command fails with "not found".

```
~/projects/garmin$ docker container run --rm -it --name monkeyc -v $(pwd):/home/garmin/ -w /home/garmin/ openjdk:13-alpine ash
/home/garmin # ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc --version
ash: ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc: not found
```

Outside the container the command works as expected

```
~/projects/garmin$ ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc --version
Connect IQ compiler version 3.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The monkeyc command is a bash script. Bash shell is not installed on alpine Linux in the container. Should use ash shell instead.
Switching from bash to ash in the monkeyc script works.

```
~/projects/garmin$ docker container run --rm -it --name monkeyc -v $(pwd):/home/garmin/ -w /home/garmin/ openjdk:13-alpine ash
/home/garmin # ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc --version
ash: ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc: not found
/home/garmin # cat ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc
#!/bin/bash

MB_HOME="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
java -classpath "$MB_HOME"/monkeybrains.jar com.garmin.monkeybrains.Monkeybrains "$@"
/home/garmin # vi ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc
/home/garmin # ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc --version
Connect IQ compiler version 3.0.3
/home/garmin # cat ./connectiq-sdk/bin/monkeyc
#!/bin/ash

MB_HOME="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
java -classpath "$MB_HOME"/monkeybrains.jar com.garmin.monkeybrains.Monkeybrains "$@"
```